# Getting a start touchPoint and end touchPoint to determine velocity AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

I'm trying to throw an object and create the angle and velocity the object is moving based on the beginning touch point and end touch point. So far I am able to track the touch points while dragging the object `mySprite`. I also have static gravity in place for when the object is released. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to link the two together.

I have a function `onTouchEnd()` that detects when the object is released and that's where the gravity kicks in. But right now nothing happens.

What am I missing to be able to pinpoint the start and end touch points and then save the angle between the two for the object's trajectory? Sorry for being such a noob.

EDIT: updated code using localX, localY

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class ThrowIt extends MovieClip{
    public var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    public var startX:int;
    public var endX:int;
    public var startY:int;
    public var endY:int;
    public var angle:int;
    //public var speed:Number = 10; //this will change based on mouse speed
    public var moving:Number = 0;
    public var speedLimit:Number = 35;
    public var scale_x:Number = Math.cos(angle);
    public var scale_y:Number = Math.sin(angle);
    public var posY:Number = stage.y;
    public var goingUp:Boolean = false;
    public var goingDown:Boolean = false;
    //public var velocityX:Number = (speed*scale_x);
    //public var velocityY:Number = (speed*scale_y);

    public function ThrowIt() {
        mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x336699); 
        mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,40,40); 
        //addChild(bg);
        addChild(mySprite); 
        mySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); 
        mySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);
    }

    function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent) { 
        mySprite.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID, false);

        /*TRACK THE START POINT OF THE DRAG HERE*/
        /*NEED THE X AND Y POSITION TO FIGURE OUT ANGLE AND VELOCITY OF OBJECT*/
        startX = e.localX;
        startY = e.localY;
        trace("the starting x is " + startX); 

    } 

    function onTouchEnd(e:TouchEvent) { 
        mySprite.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID); 
        /*TRACK THE END POINT OF THE DRAG HERE*/
        /*AGAIN, NEED BOTH THE X AND Y POSITION*/

        endY = e.localY;
        endX = e.localX;

        //angle = (endX - startX)*Math.PI(180);

        /*AFTER GETTING THE VELOCITY FIGURED OUT, THROW OBJECT*/
        if(!goingUp){
            goingUp = true;
            //moving = speedLimit*-1;
            moving = (startY - endY)*-1;
            moving += .2;
            mySprite.y += moving;
            mySprite.y = Math.min(mySprite.y, stage.stageHeight - 510); //min position of the object
            mySprite.y = Math.max(mySprite.y, 0); ///max position of the object
        }
        if(moving < 0){//if mySprite is still going up
            moving *= 1 - speedLimit/250;//decrease moving slightly
            if(moving > -speedLimit*.1){//if moving is small enough
                moving *= -1;//then begin to go down
            }
        }
        if(moving > 0 && moving <= speedLimit){//if mySprite is going down
            moving *= 1 + speedLimit/400;//increase the falling speed
        }
        mySprite.y += moving;
        //WHEN OBJECT GOES BELOW THE STAGE, DELETE IT AND STOP TRACKING EVENTS
        if(mySprite.y >= stage.stageHeight){
            removeChild(mySprite);
            mySprite.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);
            mySprite.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);

            trace("removed");
        }
    }


}

}
```

Comment: did you try with e.localX, e.localY or e.stageX, e.stageY for local or global position of the event ? before to retrieve these value for the end you have to check if the touchPointID is the same as in you touchBegin. so maybe keep a reference to the touchPointID of the start event. Maybe starting by reading the doc is a good point : [TouchEvent documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html)

Comment: @Binou thanks for sharing the resource. I had been looking over it for hours but I couldn't figure out the implementation. I updated the code above but I'm still having troubles. It seems now, when I drag the sprite towards the bottom of the screen, it just shoots off the stage (testing on Android device).

Comment: what exactily is your problem. I just see you are trying to remove event of type enterframe on the sprite instead of touches. i think it would be better to remove all the throwing code from your onTouchEnd function an put it in another function because these type of function must be called multiple times and not just on time.

Comment: The removeEventListeners for EnterFrame are a mistake on my part. They should be touchEnd and touchBegin. The code above has been updated for that mistake.

The idea is to have the sprite only be thrown once. so once you let go it gets tossed up, hits a falling point, and keeps falling down past the bottom edge of the screen. Eventually I will add a rule that won't allow the sprite to go past the top of the screen. I'm just trying to get the angle and velocity part sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating your angle using just x value seem strange, try this:

```
angle = Math.atan( (startY - endY) / (startX - endX) );  // in rad
```

This will give you the angle in radian.

For calculating the velocity you must have a timing variable between the start and the end touch. You can use `getTimer()` to get `beginTime` and `endTime` in your functions `onTouchBegin` and `onTouchEnd` respectively.

After that you just have to calculate velocity with distance and time.

```
distance = Math.sqrt( ((startX - endX)*(startX - endX)) / ((startY - endY)*(startY - endY)) );
velocity = distance / (endTime-beginTime); // in pixel/ms
```

Hope that helps ;)